# PHP 5.6 isn't supported with security, So Why PHP 5.6 is not deprecated yet?

Tags: php, php-5.6

> PHP 5.6 is the past end of life and isn't supported with security
> updates.

I've been doing web development for a little over a year and started learning and working with PHP 6 months now (part-time, still doing my masters).

Every day there are changes or modification I have to do so get active work.

My latest project is building a web platform I've been doing web development for a little over a year and started learning and working with PHP 7 months now (part-time, still doing my masters).

There are many problems with PHP 5.6 and previous versions.

My latest project is building a web platform (from scratch) for a startup that pairs people up, but progress has been slow. I've been working on this part-time for months, learning as I go. Now the startup recently hired a remote part-time PHP expert to help speed things up. This new guy took one look at my code, said it was bad and messy, and said he will re-do everything from scratch himself, in under a week. The startup basically just said to roll with it and continue on once the code is in. I'm afraid that I will be replaced in a heartbeat here, and that the past 6 months of learning PHP was for nothing.

> So Why PHP 5.6 is not deprecated yet?
>
> Any advice or tips on how to be a better programmer in PHP?

Comment: Because PHP 7 is cheerful

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you ask this?

Comment: I don't think PHP versions in themselves gets deprecated, it will no longer be officially maintained or supported is all.

Comment: there is nothing like deprecated regarding php version-> simply maintenance and support for that version stopped at all.

Comment: You probably mean PHP 5.6, and not PHP 6?

Comment: [Check out the migration notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php) and keep learning. Check out what the other developer has to offer; it could be a great learning opportunity. If you get replaced, try not to be too discouraged and move on to another project.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I guess it's ment to say "working with PHP ***for*** 6 months" (emphasized word is mine)

Comment: Yeah PHP 5.6. I am using APIs from the external server, everyday I have to do something otherwise there are errors.

Comment: @Qirel Ah yes, of course.

Comment: Recently https://www.carlo.in/calculator not working, "Calculate Your EMI" . can anyone fix?

Comment: "So Why PHP 5.6 is not deprecated yet?" — It is! That is what End of Life means! (If you are asking why your hosting provider is selling you a service running on out of date software: Ask them.)

Comment: @Quentin My whole project is on PHP 5.6. So not working means all of my work will be wastage. It is not mistaken for them(Hosting Provider). Code written by the previous developer is on PHP 5.6

Comment: That's not true. You can update your PHP version (a lot of providers give you the choice to choose the PHP versions), and you should if you can. Learn PHP7 instead. There are some changes between PHP5.6 and PHP 7.3, but if you read the migration documentation, you can learn how to improve it and update it. Keep learning, it takes experience to become a good developer - and you get experience by doing.

Comment: Plenty of PHP 5.6 code runs without changes on PHP 7.x. When changes are needed, they are usually minor. Your work isn't wasted.

Comment: Have you read the [migrating guide from PHP 5.6.x to PHP 7.0.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php)? Upgrading can be easier than you think.

Comment: Yeah, I already had look on the guide. But these all are out of my syllabus.

Comment: PHP 5.6 is not deprecated yet, because most of the products are still work with it and build on it. just think what will happen if PHP 5.6 stopped working. A lot of websites stopped working including many government websites. well, government websites usually prefer java, but still, there will be some which support PHP. There is a lot of product based company whose big projects are made on PHP 5.6 and hiring new employees to recode the whole project in PHP 7 is a big mess and cost-effective.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Well, the version itself doesn't get deprecated - but it has reached its end of life, and should not be used with new projects (if one can avoid it). It won't stop working on live projects, as the PHP version is loaded on the specific server - The PHP developers have no control over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because most of the products are still work with it and build on it. just think what will happen if PHP 5.6 stopped working. A lot of websites will be stopped working including many government websites. well, government websites usually prefer java, but still, there will be some which support PHP. There is a lot of product based company whose big projects are made on PHP 5.6 and hiring new employees to recode the whole project in PHP 7 is a big mess and cost-effective.